# _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() gives a leak for a simple new int()

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, new-operator, crt

This code:

```
int *pi = new int();

_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

gives me a leak of 4 bytes. Why?

My pointer pi is pointing to the allocated memory. I would understand the leak if I had wrote pi = nullptr, but I did not. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps becaus you did not delete it before calling `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`. You actually have a leak. Assigning nullptr would not affect the state of the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` should be called at the end of the program, after all memory has been freed. It does not check if there are pointers to the memory-blocks or not.

Answer (score 1):

The size of your pointer is four bytes which are allocated and not freed.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d41t22sb.aspx,
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks calls _CrtMemCheckpoint to obtain the current state of the heap and then scans the state for blocks that have not been freed.